# Video-React: How to detect when the event when user played or paused the video?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, video-reactjs

I am trying to execute some logic **whenever the user plays/pauses a video** that is implemented using [Video-React](https://video-react.js.org/):

```
<Player
  ref={(player) => {
    this.player = player;
  }}
  src={videoURL}
>
  <BigPlayButton position="center" />
  <ControlBar autoHide={false} className="my-class"></ControlBar>
</Player>;
```

So the user can **play/pause the video** in **three** ways:

1. Using the `BigPlayButton` he can play the video:
   [image]
2. Using the play/pause button in the control bar:
   [image]
3. Clicking on the video itself will play/pause it.

**So, I need to detect whenever any of those three events happen.**

For the **first event**, *"Using the `BigPlayButton` he can play the video"*, it has been [suggested](https://github.com/video-react/video-react/issues/307) that I customize the button itself.

For the **second event**,*"Using the play/pause button in the control bar"*, I didn't find anything that shows how I can detect the onClick event when the user clicks on one of the control bar buttons.

For the **third event**,*"Clicking on the video itself will play/pause it."*, I didn't find anything.

I thought using the state like it's mentioned in the [documentation](https://video-react.js.org/components/player/) would easily solve all three:

> State We use redux to manage the player state. Using getState method
> can get the state object. This is the list of all the states.

This partly solves the **paused** problem:

> paused:Returns whether the player has been paused

But, I did not find a state property that changes whenever the video gets played. The closest thing to this is **hasStarted**:

> hasStarted:Returns whether the video has been started

The problem with hasStarted is that it gets set to true the when the video gets played the first time.
And so subsequenty **play(s)** will not get detected.
And I find myself in an ambiguous state where `this.player.paused` & `this.player.hasStarted` are both `true`.
Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: `gets played` means the user paused and then play again?

Comment: @MoshFeu User plays the video